# Java Application hang in Fedora but not in Windows

Tags: java

When I learn the *Thinking in Java(4th)* book. I just type in the concurrency/CriticalSection.java code and run it in the terminal of Fedora, but it hang up.

While I ran it in the Windows cmd. It works.

I don't know why it hang in Fedora but not in Windows.

I really did a little analysation. When I add *System.out.println(name)* to the run() method of PairManipulator. It works out the result , but when I comment it, the application don't give the result ,it just hang there.

The JDK & JVM Information:

Windows:

```
java version "1.8.0_25"
Java<TM> SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_25-b18)
Java HotSpot<TM> 64-bit Server VM(build 25.25-b02, mixed mode)
```

Fedora:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_45"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-b14)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode)
```

Here is the code:

```
package concurrency;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;


class Pair{
    private int x, y;
    public Pair(int x, int y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public Pair(){
        this(0, 0);
    }

    public int getX(){
        return x;
    }

    public int getY(){
        return y;
    }

    public void incrementX(){
        x++;
    }

    public void incrementY(){
        y++;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return "x: " + x + ", y: " + y;
    }

    public class PairValuesNotEqualException extends RuntimeException{
        public PairValuesNotEqualException(){
            super("Pair values not equal: " + Pair.this);
        }
    }

    public void checkState(){
        if(x != y)
            throw new PairValuesNotEqualException();
    }
}


abstract class PairManager{
    AtomicInteger checkCounter = new AtomicInteger(0);
    protected Pair p = new Pair();
    private List<Pair> storage = 
            Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<Pair>());

    public synchronized Pair getPair(){
        return new Pair(p.getX(), p.getY());
    }

    protected void store(Pair p){
        storage.add(p);
        try {
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(50);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO 自动生成的 catch 块
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public abstract void increment();

}

class PairManager1 extends PairManager{

    @Override
    public synchronized void increment() {
        // TODO 自动生成的方法存根
        p.incrementX();
        p.incrementY();
        store(getPair());
    }

}

class PairManager2 extends PairManager{

    @Override
    public void increment() {
        // TODO 自动生成的方法存根
        Pair temp;
        synchronized(this){
            p.incrementX();
            p.incrementY();
            temp = getPair();
        }

        store(temp);
    }

}

class PairManipulator implements Runnable{
    private PairManager pm;
    //private String name;
    public PairManipulator(PairManager pm){
        this.pm = pm;
        //this.name = name;
    }


    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO 自动生成的方法存根
        while(true){
            //System.out.println(name);
            pm.increment();

        }

    }

    public String toString(){
        return "Pair: " + pm.getPair() + " checkCounter  = " + pm.checkCounter.get();
    }

}

class PairChecker implements Runnable{
    private PairManager pm;
    //private String name;
    public PairChecker(PairManager pm){
        this.pm = pm;
        //this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO 自动生成的方法存根
        while(true){
            //System.out.println(name);
            pm.checkCounter.incrementAndGet();
            pm.getPair().checkState();
        }
    }
}

public class CriticalSection {

    static void testApproaches(PairManager pman1, PairManager pman2){
        ExecutorService exec = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        PairManipulator
            pm1 = new PairManipulator(pman1),
            pm2 = new PairManipulator(pman2);

        PairChecker
            pcheck1 = new PairChecker(pman1),
            pcheck2 = new PairChecker(pman2);


        exec.execute(pm1);
        exec.execute(pm2);
        exec.execute(pcheck1);
        exec.execute(pcheck2);


        try {
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(500);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO 自动生成的 catch 块
            System.out.println("Sleep interrupted");
        }

        System.out.println("pm1: " + pm1 + "\npm2: " + pm2);
        System.exit(0);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO 自动生成的方法存根

        PairManager
            pman1 = new PairManager1(),
            pman2 = new PairManager2();

        testApproaches(pman1, pman2);

    }

}
```

Comment: It's very difficult to say anything from the above code.Can you be more specific ?Like what exception/error you get?system details? A [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: Did you try to analyse anyhing? Where does it hang? Did you try to add logging statements? Did you try to debug? Or did you do no analysation at all and simply posted this bunch of code here?

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose Sorry.I really did a little analysation. When  I add _System.out.println(name)_ to the run() method of PairManipulator. It works out the result , but when I comment it, the application don't give the result ,it just hang there. In addition, because I am new to Java. Would you please suggest some tools so I can make a further work. Thanks

Comment: Do you use the same JDK on Fedora? Fedora installs the openJDK instead of Oracles'

Comment: @Cerbis I add the JDK information, thanks for your advice.

Comment: @joeyrohan I add the JDK information.

Comment: While `System.exit` should indeed terminate your program it would be better if each thread ended gracefully on it's own. I think the program doesn't really hang but the shutdown process is slowed down by the four threads that are busy doing stuff. On my Mac the program takes about 30 seconds to complete. If I add a 1 ms delay in the two `while (true)` loops it completes within a second as you would expect when you call `System.exit()` after half a second.

Comment: @Eelke You are right! I just run it and hava a nap, while I wake up. it gives the result! It seems that when the main thread run to the _System.out.println("pm1: " + pm1 + "\npm2: " + pm2)_ then it was hang up, then switch to the four threads doing some stuff, after some time , switch back again, and the result was print and _System.exit(0)_ was executed. What confuse me is, under windows, it seems the code run to the end immediately but under linux (or mac) it really need some time.